# Worklight call WL.Server.invokeHttp(input) in a loop

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-adapters

I am novice to Worklight.
I am trying to merge responses from multiple WL.Server.invokeHttp(input).

e.g.

```
call1:  response1 = WL.Server.invokeHttp(input1) 
lets say in response1 I get students(names) list loop for every student 
call(n):
response(n) = WL.Server.invokeHttp(student) lets say response(n) I get
the score of student
```

Now I am trying to merge the score of every student in student list.

Adding code:

```
function getStudentsMarks() {
    path = "/edu/students";
    WL.Logger.info("path: "+path);
    var input = {
        method : 'get',
        returnedContentType : 'json',
        path : path
    };
    var response = WL.Server.invokeHttp(input);
    var students = response.students;
    for (var i = 0; i < students.length; i++) {
        var student = students[i];
        WL.Logger.info("student id: " + student.id);
        resp = getStudentMarks("students/"+student.id);
        students[i].marks = resp;
    }

    return response;
}

function getStudentMarks(path) {
    path = "/edu/"+ path;
    var input = {
        method : 'get',
        returnedContentType : 'json',
        path : path
    };
    var response = WL.Server.invokeHttp(input);

    return response;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The idea seems right, but need to test with the data - did you try? Any errors? expected results?

Comment: But your procedure is currently returning 'response' at the end. I think you want 'students'?

Comment: I tried but the final response took long time.
I am also worried about if any service call fails.

Comment: Yes, I need to collect all students data and then send single response .

Comment: If your loop calls an external service hundreds of time, I imagine it will be too long and fail. Check with a shorter list of 3 students for example. Also like said, the last line of getStudentsMark should be 'students' not 'response'.

Comment: Can I configure some caching? Like for the first request, time will be too long but for the future  requests I can get cached response.
Later on I do cache the response at regular interval of time.
Please share your opinion.

Comment: If you are having to do this, there's a good chance that your back-end services aren't well-constructed for this scenario. I'd recommend revisiting their design to see if there's a way to remove the need for this loop, by returning all the data you need in one payload.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is a bit too broad and does not contain any code.

Did you try anything yet?

It is important to remember that procedure code is written in JavaScript. So if you know how to do it in JavaScript, you should be able to do it in procedure code as well.

From what I understand, what you should do is create 1 adapter procedure. This procedure will have the different calls to the different HTTP backend requests. In JavaScript, write any merging logic that you need. At the end of the loop, return the processed data that you want.

Before you go deep into your example, maybe try with just 1 invocation, then try to merge 2. Once you are comfortable writing code, try your solution.

Note however that one HTTP adapter can only connect to 1 backend domain name. So if your example requires multiple domain names, your "mashup" adapter needs to call other adapters.
If all your HTTP requests point to the same domain name, then 1 adapter is enough.

I recommend reading this as well: https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/worklight/entry/handling_backend_responses_in_adapters

Comment: added code. please suggest if it is the correct way to do it.